# Vite + Vue3 + Fontawesome cauging syntax error

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs3, vite

I migrated my vue3 project today from Webpack to Vite.

To make font awesome work I used the SVG plugin for vite and everything works correct in dev mode.

As soon as I want to build my project I get an syntax error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Which is caused by the fontawesome-svg-core package in line 463 which is the following

```
if (!promise._handled && isNode) {
  global.process.emit('unhandledRejection', promise._data, promise);
}
```

This error makes no sense to me, anybody knows how to fix is or where I went wrong during my migration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-fontawesome?file=src%2FApp.vue). Can you fork the demo and recreate the problem?

Comment: @tony19 Thanks for the hint, totally forget to try and reproduce the error. I figured out what was causing the issue, when running it on vite preview I got an error in  my console "global is not defined" which was caused by aws cognito sdk, so I added it to defines in my vite config, however this collided with the "global" from font awesome.